# What's wrong with my Python 2 program?

Tags: python, python-2.7

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1145

*Write an program that reads two numbers X and Y (X < Y). After this, show a sequence of 1 to y, passing to the next line to each X numbers.*

**Input**
*The input contains two integer numbers X (1 < X < 20) and Y (X < Y < 100000).*

**Output**
*Each sequence must be printed in one line, with a blank space between each number.*

[image: output should look like this]

My code is here:

```
x,y = raw_input().split(" ")

x = int(x)
xr = x
y = int(y)

lis = []

for i in range(1, y+1):
    lis.append(i)

j = 0

for i in range(1, y+1):
    while j <= x:
        try:
            if j < x:
                print str(lis[j]),
                j=j+1
            else:
                if x == y:
                    break
                else:
                    print ""
                    x = xr + x
        except IndexError:
            break
```

Code's output is accurate. But the website is not accepting my code for some reason. Please help me find the bug?

Comment: Meaningful title, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem in on the line `print str(lis[j]),`, which add a space after the third digit and the site don't consider this valid, the problem say "with a blank space between each number." and maybe this is considered invalid.

Another possible solution is to split the list with the X numbers in lists of Y elements and print them with something like `print " ".join(lis[Xs:Xf])`

Comment: seems like that Space after the last output on each line is actually causing the problem. 
is there any way to string.replace() it?

Comment: The `print str(lis[j]),` doesn't add that space. The `print ""` does. Should just be `print`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just print you probably don't need list.
I don't know how to format code from phone.

```
sx,sy = raw_input().split(" ")

x = int(sx)

y = int(sy)

lines = int(y/x)+1

for line in range(lines):
    offset = x*line
    for i in range(x):
        print i+offset,
        if i+offset>=y:
            print
            break
    print
```